# wxWidgets - modeless wxDialog

Tags: c++, user-interface, pointers, dialog, wxwidgets

I am creating my own subclass of wxDialog and it works well when used as a modeless dialog like so:

```
AddDialog newAddDialog = new AddDialog(this, wxID_ANY, _T("Dialog Title"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
if (newAddDialog.ShowModal() == wxID_OK)
{
//do something
}
```

When using ShowModal(), the flow of the program stops until OK or Cancel is pressed. I need the dialog to show up, but not stop the flow of the GUI, so I tried this:

```
AddDialog newAddDialog = new AddDialog(this, wxID_ANY, _T("Dialog Title"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
if (newAddDialog.Showl() == wxID_OK)
{
//do something
}
```

When using Show(), the dialog briefly shows up and then disappears. I thought it might be a scope issue, so I used a pointer for newAddDialog. Then, the dialog shows up, when when I click OK or Cancel, the dialog closes, but the if statement code does not execute even if OK is clicked.

Does anyone know how to proceed? Thanks.

---

Further clarification:

I have virtual void function in my Dialog subclass that I overide in another class. I can't seem to get the event working when I overide, however, if I have a void in the actual Dialog subclass, I get the event call. This seems to be an overide problem, but I don't know what the problem would be. This is not the main GUI that I'm calling in the OnInit() call - could that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

`ShowModal` blocks execution of your program and returns the outcome (like wxID_OK). On the other hand, `Show` just shows the dialog and returns immediately, so you can't check the outcome (what the user pressed for buttons) from it's return value. Instead you have to communicate the outcome of that dialog-box by sending an event from withing the dialog or something like that.

Comment: I've done it by adding an event to the wxID_OK button. However, the event function is not called regardless.

Comment: Added further clarification in my main post.

Answer (score 0):

```
AddDialog newAddDialog = new AddDialog(...
```

Does this compile?  Really?

The 'new' operator returns a pointer to void, so the code you have posted looks very odd indeed.

The usual way of doing this is:

```
AddDialog * newAddDialog = (AddDialog *) new AddDialog( ...
```

Or

```
AddDialog newAddDialog( ...
```